# IF Cells in row are greater than today

Tags: excel

I can figure how to do this this formula for individual cells but I wondered if it was possible to list cells that I want to apply the formula to in one formula?

```
=IF((BL1675,BO1675,BR1675,BU1675,BX1675,CA1675,CD1675)>TODAY(),"No Action Req","Action Req")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean any of these listed cells is greater than `TODAY` or all cells?

Comment: Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but `=IF(AND(BL1675>TODAY(),BO1675>TODAY(),BR1675>TODAY(),BU1675>TODAY(),BX1675>TODAY(),CA1675>TODAY(),CD1675>TODAY()),"No Action Req","Action Req")` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Use CHOOSE in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},BL1675,BO1675,BR1675,BU1675,BX1675,CA1675,CD1675)>TODAY()))=7,"No Action Req","Action Req")
```

The above will return the `"Action Req"` if any are less than or equal to `TODAY()`.  If all you want is if one or more are greater than `TODAY()`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},BL1675,BO1675,BR1675,BU1675,BX1675,CA1675,CD1675)>TODAY())),"No Action Req","Action Req")
```

Comment: The latter is exactly what i was after . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `(A1, A2, ...)>TODAY()`, there are other ways to do that:

You want all of them being larger than today:

```
=AND(A1>TODAY(), A2>TODAY(), ...) // as mentioned in Plutian's comment.
```

You want at least one of them being larger than today:

```
=OR(A1>TODAY(), A2>TODAY(), ...)
```

Or, you might go for a more elegant approach:

All of them being larger than today, means that the smallest must be larger:

```
=MIN(A1, A2, ...)>TODAY()
```

At least one of them being larger than today, means that the largest must be larger:

```
=MAX(A1, A2, ...)>TODAY()
```